# Splitting a filename

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, split

I've a filename:

```
NewReport-20140423_17255375-BSIQ-2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip
```

How can i split the above filename to 4 string groups.

```
NewReport
20140423_17255375
BSIQ
2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip
```

I tried:

```
 string[] strFileTokens = filename.Split(new char[]{'-'} , StringSplitOptions.None);
```

but i'm not getting the above required four strings

Comment: string[] strFileTokens = filename.Split(new[] { '-' }, 4);

Comment: It will split 2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip too. So you get more chunks right?

Comment: No. i dont want split of `2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify the maximum number of substrings to return:

```
var strFileTokens = filename.Split(new[] { '-' }, 4, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This will avoid splitting `2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip` into additional "pieces".

*(Also, you can drop* `StringSplitOptions.None` *since that's the default.)*

---

Internally, it creates an array of substrings inside a loop, and it only loops the number of times you specify (or the maximum number of delimiters available in your string, whichever is less).

```
for (int i = 0; i < numActualReplaces && currIndex < Length; i++)
{
    splitStrings[arrIndex++] = Substring(currIndex, sepList[i] - currIndex );
    currIndex = sepList[i] + ((lengthList == null) ? 1 : lengthList[i]); 
}
```

The variable `numActualReplaces` is the minimum of either the count you specify, or the number of actual delimiters present in your string. *(That way, if you specify a larger number like 30, but you only have 7 hyphens in the string, you won't get an exception. Actually, when you don't specify a number at all, it's actually using* `Int32.MaxValue` *without you even realizing it.)*

---

You updated your question to say you're using Silverlight, which doesn't have he overloads with `Count`. That's really annoying, because under the hood the `string` class still supports it. They just didn't provide a way to pass in your own value. It uses a hard-coded `int.MaxValue`.

You could create your own method to bring back the desired functionality. I haven't tested this extension method out for all edge-cases, but it does work with your string.

```
public static class StringSplitExtension
{
    public static string[] SplitByCount(this string input, char[] separator, int count)
    {
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");

        if (count == 0)
            return new string[0];

        var numberOfSeparators = input.Count(separator.Contains);

        var numActualReplaces = Math.Min(count, numberOfSeparators + 1);

        var splitString = new string[numActualReplaces];

        var index = -1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= numActualReplaces; i++)
        {
            var nextIndex = input.IndexOfAny(separator, index + 1);
            if (nextIndex == -1 || i == numActualReplaces)
                splitString[i - 1] = input.Substring(index + 1);
            else
                splitString[i - 1] = input.Substring(index + 1, nextIndex - index - 1);
            index = nextIndex;
        }

        return splitString;
    }
}
```

Make sure it's somewhere accessible to your UserControl, then call it like this:

```
var strFileTokens = filename.SplitByCount(new[] { '-' }, 4)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting only 3 overloads for the `Split` method. the count or Int32 overload is not coming in my Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: yes...I'm getting only 1st, 3rd and 4th overloads. why?? I'm using VS2010 Professional

Comment: got to know that it is because of Silverlight app. where it has only three overloads.

Answer (score 3):

It works if you call the [overload of `Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) that takes a `count` parameter:

```
var myArray = filename.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using silverlight as shown in your [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23334559/284240) which doesn't have this overload i show a different approach. You could use LINQ's `Skip`, `Take` + `string.Join` to get one `string`:

Your sample string:

```
string filename = "NewReport-20140423_17255375-BSIQ-2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip";
```

An array with all parts:

```
string[] allTokens = filename.Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var firstThreeToken = allTokens.Take(3);  // first three
var lastTokens = allTokens.Skip(3);       // the last part 
string lastToken = string.Join("-", lastTokens); // last tokens as single string
string[] allToken = firstThreeToken.Concat(new[] { lastToken }).ToArray();
```

Result:

```
"NewReport" 
"20140423_17255375"
"BSIQ"
"2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Regex.Split` method which offers an overload that takes the count param.

[image]

```
Regex reg = new Regex( "-" );
string filename = "NewReport-20140423_17255375-BSIQ-2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip";
var parts = reg.Split( filename, 4 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you are getting more parts because the last part of your file also contains "-".

An easy way to solve it is to join the remaining parts like this:

```
String lastpart = string.Join("-", names, 3, names.Length - 3);
```