# No Count overload for a String Split method in Silverlight application

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, split

Reference to question at [Splitting a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295134/splitting-a-filename)

In the Silverlight Application since there is no `Count` overload, I require the expected result as four string elements.

```
NewReport
20140423_17255375
BSIQ
2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip
```

This line of code is getting build errors in my silverlight application

```
var strFileTokens = filename.Split(new[] { '-' }, 4, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Build Error:
Error   4

```
The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(string[], int, System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments    C:\TestSolution\Reporting.cs    287
```

How to get the above four string elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the overload that takes a maximum count of returned sub-strings is not supportewd in silverlight. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is the silverlight overview.

So you need to use a workaround, if you want to take only 4. You can use `Split` + `Enumerable.Take`:

```
string[] strFileTokens = filename
    .Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
    .Take(4)
    .ToArray();
```

I would use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to omit empty tokens. If you don't need it as array you can omit `ToArray` and execute it lazily which can be more efficient.

**Update**: now i've recognized from your other question that you want to take the first three elements and the last. So if this is your file-name:

```
string filename = "NewReport-20140423_17255375-BSIQ-2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip";
```

You want this `string[]:`

```
"NewReport" 
"20140423_17255375"
"BSIQ"
"2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip"
```

You could use LINQ's `Skip` and `Take` + `string.Join` to get one string for the last tokens:

```
string[] allTokens = filename.Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var firstThreeToken = allTokens.Take(3);
var lastTokens = allTokens.Skip(3);
string lastToken = string.Join("-", lastTokens);
string[] allToken = firstThreeToken.Concat(new[] { lastToken }).ToArray();
```

Comment: The 4th element is returning just `2wd28830` but it is not giving the expected `2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip`

Comment: @sukumar: what is the complete path to this file? What are you using to extract the file-name? You should either use `FileInfo` or the `Path`-class. Why do you get `2wd28830` as 4th(last) element if it's the first in the file-name?

Comment: the complete filename is `NewReport-20140423_17255375-BSIQ-2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip` which i'm getting as response in `string` from the WCF service call.

Comment: IS there a single LINQ query for your recent answer?

Comment: @sukumar: why, do you have multiple file-names? If so, from where do you have them? You have just provided one string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Regex.Split` method which offers an overload that takes the count param.

[image]

```
Regex reg = new Regex( "-" );
string filename = "NewReport-20140423_17255375-BSIQ-2wd28830-841c-4d30-95fd-a57a7aege412.zip";
var parts = reg.Split( filename, 4 );
```